# App ID not available while upload iOS archive file through Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, testflight

I'm getting following error while uploading archive file to the iTunes connect. I've already uploaded the same app's archive to iTunes twice, second time with different bundle version. And my internal test users were able to download and run the app just fine. But now I'm getting this error and I can't put my finger on something I'm doing wrong. Please do help me identify. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Check if you have the App ID with your bundle identifier registered for your configured team Apple Developer account

Comment: Information used on Developer portal and in the app project should be totally identical